# Incorrect message about another post closed as a duplicate when voting to delete

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

I voted to delete a post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917570/i-want-code-gold-price-php (closed as not a real question)

I got this message:

[image]

Which refers to this post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928507/want-becomes-code-gold-price (closed as not a real question)

It wasn't actually closed as a duplicate, but it looks like somebody may have voted to close as such:

> [possible duplicate of I want code gold price php – Fabrício Matté 7 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928507/want-becomes-code-gold-price#comment20948008_14928507)

Is this intentional?

Comment: `I'm sorry, please help me to get the gold prices` Oh wow. That's not a help vampire any more. That's a help **zombie**

Comment: "I want code gold price php"... Sorry let me clarify that: "I *need* code php gold prices".

Comment: I guess it's to avoid a broken link at the other end? Just voted to delete the newer/dupe question.

Comment: Pretty ballsy move on his part, reposting the exact same question just one day later, and then having the nerve to thank his friends in advance.... When his other post was already shot dead...

Comment: I was trying to give him the benefit of doubt :P you are most likely correct.