# Delete vote alert is not very helpful. Can we please have something better?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

I tried to delete a question recently. I get this alert box that asks me whether I'm sure that I want to vote to delete. That's fine, there's no need for something better. But then I get this:

[image: Alert]

How the hell am I supposed to know whether post 13382262 is important or not? Who knows, maybe that post should get deleted as well. That's not very helpful of the site.

### Some points

- You can't copy/paste an ID from the alert box.
- You can't switch focus to the browser without dismissing the alert box.

Can we please get something more decent? No need to get fancy, a simple link to the duplicate would be sufficient, a proper model even better. Anything's better than the default alert.

Comment: (Side-Note) I'm confused... [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382262/where-does-node-js-fit-in-a-stack-or-enhance-it) is not closed as a duplicate... Am I missing something here?

Comment: A proper modal instead of a standard js dialog would be much better

Comment: @animuson It's linked and closed, maybe that already counts?

Comment: @animuson: Not sure, but that's the alert I got

Comment: @animuson [Incorrect message about another post closed as a duplicate when voting to delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167977) (one of the voters presumably voted as such, even though that wasn't the outcome)

Comment: Perhaps someone has marked it as a duplicate but it's closed as not constructive because that reason succeeded in getting 5 votes earlier?

Comment: Also 1 *posts*?!1!one That's needless pluralization *and* genericization!

Comment: I agree the way this information appears is intrusive, but it is also important. You should check the closed post, and reconsider your delete vote. Otherwise, an important topic may entirely disappear from the site, if you're shoot your delete votes like a machine gun

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: He's not complaining it's intrusive. He's complaining that for how important it is, it's awfully inconvenient to investigate it. It gives you an ID, which (AFAIK) you can't even copy-paste from a dialog box, so you actually have to type it in manually to get to the question it's telling you about.

Comment: Yes you can copy/paste, at least in Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: -1 for not having memorized all post ids on the site (yet?).

Comment: @Yannis: I immediately checked for downvotes. :P

Comment: @animuson, it seems I got it wrong then. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @animuson: Not only that! You can't copy/paste, you can't even switch focus to the browser without dismissing it! You practically can't do anything short of opening a new browser window, or memorizing the ID in your head to write it down after you close the alert box.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That sounds like a real bug to me.

Comment: Since a post can have multiple questions using it as a duplicate, I would suggest a good solution to this would be to add a "Duplicates"  list with "Linked" and "Related" in the right sidebar

Comment: I've never seen this.

Comment: Multiple confirmation is sooo Microsoft. I thot StackExchange was better than that.

Answer (score 11):

A possible (partial) solution to this would be to add another, **Duplicates** section in the right sidebar, where all the duplicates of a question are listed.

[image: Example]

This could be a *partial* solution, as it doesn't address the original problem (where the alert box is unusable), it does solve the mystery regarding what posts are closed as duplicates of this.

Comment: 9001 "Where are my legs?"